# Preparing csv data to ML

Tags: python, machine-learning

I would like to implement ML model for classification problem. My csv data looks like this:

Method1; Method2; Method3; Method4; Category; Class
result1; result2; result3; result4; Sport; 12
...
...

All methods, gives a text. Sometimes it is a one word, sometimes more and sometimes the cell is empty (no answer for this method). Column "category" always has a text and column "class" is a numerical showing number of method with correct answer (i.e. number 12 means that only result from method 1 and 2 is correct). Maybe will add more column if necessary.

Now, having a new answers from all methods I would like to classify it to one of the class.

How should I prepare this data? I know I should have a numerical data but how to do that, and handle with all empty cells, and inconsistent number of words in each answer?

Answer (score 0):

> How should I prepare this data? I know I should have a numerical data but how to do that, and handle with all empty cells, and inconsistent number of words in each answer?

There are many different ways of doing this, but the most simple would be to just use a [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) representation, which means concatenating all your `Methodx` columns and counting how many times does each word appears on them.

With that, you have a vector representation (each word is a column/feature, each count is a numerical value).

Now, from here there are several problems (the main one is that the number of columns/features in your dataset will be quite large), so you may have to either preprocess your data further or find a ML technique that can dealt with it for you. But, in any case, I would recommend to try to have a look at several tutorials on NLP to get a better idea of this and get a better estimation of what would be the best solution for your dataset.